# No se puede convertir ‘char* (*)[10][81]’ a ‘char*’

Tags: c, socket

Bien, mi problema es el siguiente:

Al tratar de compilar este código en linux (gcc server.cpp -o server
):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

const int TAM_COLA = 10;
const int TAM_TEXTO = 80;
const int ESPERASEG = 0;
const int ESPERAMILISEG = 1;
/*
int EnterPulsado();
int CrearSocket(unsigned short puerto);
void CerrarSockets(int sock, int cola, int num);
void CerrarSocket(int sock, int num);
int AceptarConexion(int sock, int cola, int num);
int Leer(int sock, int cola, int* num, char buffer);
int Escribir(int sock, int cola, int num, char buffer, int cont);
*/

int EnterPulsado()
{
      fd_set conjunto;
      struct timeval t;
      FD_ZERO(&conjunto);
      FD_SET(0,&conjunto); /* 0 es el identificador del socket de stdin */
      t.tv_sec=0;
      t.tv_usec=1000; /* 1 milisegundo */
      return select(1,&conjunto,NULL,NULL,&t); /* En caso de error devuelve ­1 y
                                                  saldremos del programa. */
}

int CrearSocket(unsigned short puerto)
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in dir;

    //Comprobación socket

    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(0);
    }

    //Asignacion de puerto al socket

    dir.sin_family=PF_INET;
    dir.sin_port=htons(puerto);
    dir.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&dir,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))!=0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(0);
    }
}
void CerrarSocket(int sock, int num)
{
    if (close(sock)<0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        num--;
}

void CerrarSockets(int sock, int *cola, int num)
{
    int aux = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        aux = cola[i];
        CerrarSocket(aux, num);
    }

    num++;

    CerrarSocket(sock, num);
}



int AceptarConexion(int sock, int *cola, int num)
{
    int accept(int s, struct sockaddr *addr, int *addrlen);   
    int sock_conectado;
    struct sockaddr_in s;
    int aux = TAM_COLA;
    if ((sock_conectado = accept(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&s,&aux)) < 0)
    {
        perror("accept");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        num++;

    return num;
}

int Leer(int sock, int *cola, int* num, char* buffer)   ///< Si se queja, dejar buffer como char
{
    int n, s;
    fd_set conjunto;
    struct timeval timeout;

    //select

    FD_ZERO(&conjunto);
    FD_SET(sock, &conjunto);

    timeout.tv_sec = ESPERASEG;
    timeout.tv_usec = ESPERAMILISEG;

    if ((n = select(s+1, &conjunto, NULL, NULL, &timeout)) < 0)
    {
        perror("select");
        exit(0);
    }

    //Leer
    if ((n = read(s, buffer, TAM_COLA)) < 0)
    {
        perror("read");
        exit(0);
    }

    return n;
}

int Escribir(int sock, int *cola, int num, char* buffer, int cont)
{
    int write(int fd, void *buf, int num);
    int n, s;
    fd_set conjunto;
    struct timeval timeout;

    //select

    FD_ZERO(&conjunto);
    FD_SET(s, &conjunto);

    timeout.tv_sec = ESPERASEG;
    timeout.tv_usec = ESPERAMILISEG;

    if ((n = select(s+1, &conjunto, NULL, NULL, &timeout)) < 0)
    {
        perror("select");
        exit(0);
    }

    //write

    if (write(s, buffer, strlen(buffer))==-1)
    {
        perror("write");
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
      char* buffer[TAM_COLA][TAM_TEXTO+1];
      int sock,cola[TAM_COLA],num,cont;

      /*if (argc!=2)
            Uso(argv[0]);*/

      sock=CrearSocket((unsigned short)atoi(argv[1])); /* Creamos el socket. */
      num = 0;

      while (EnterPulsado()==0) /* Mientras no pulsemos la tecla [Enter]. */
      {
            num = AceptarConexion(sock,cola,num); /* Miramos si hay conexiones nuevas. */
            if ((cont = Leer(sock,cola,&num,&buffer)) > 0) /* Miramos si tenemos datos para leer. */
                Escribir(sock,cola,num,&buffer,cont); /* Enviamos los datos leidos. */
            else
                CerrarSocket(sock, num);
      }

      CerrarSockets(sock,cola,num); /* Cerramos todas las conexiones. */
      return 0;
}
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

```
server.cpp: En la función ‘int main(int, char**)’:
server.cpp:192:52: error: no se puede convertir ‘char* (*)[10][81]’ a ‘char*’ para el argumento ‘4’ para ‘int Leer(int, int*, int*, char*)’
             if ((cont = Leer(sock,cola,&num,&buffer)) > 0) /* Miramos si tenemos datos para leer. */
                                                    ^
server.cpp:193:52: error: no se puede convertir ‘char* (*)[10][81]’ a ‘char*’ para el argumento ‘4’ para ‘int Escribir(int, int*, int, char*, int)’
                 Escribir(sock,cola,num,&buffer,cont); /* Enviamos los datos leidos. */
```

Como puedo corregirlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por favor, lee los consejos acerda de [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

No es necesario pegar todo el código de tu aplicación, para reproducir el problema hubiera bastado con incluir la función Leer o Escribir vacias (tan sólo con un return). Incluir todo el código de la aplicación dificulta la compresión de la pregunta (y por lo tanto, que el resto podamos ayudarte).

Tu problema radica en la definición del buffer que estás utilizando. Con esto:

```
char* buffer[TAM_COLA][TAM_TEXTO+1];
```

Estas definiendo una MATRIZ de dos dimensaiones de punteros a `char`, cuando realmente lo que necesitas es un array de chars.

```
char buffer[ (TAM_COLA*TAM_TEXTO)+1 ];
```

Suerte